# Qt Android kit configuration

Tags: qt

I tried to build a project for android and i got these warnings:

> :-1: avertissement :
>   "D:\Dev\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
>   is used by qmake, but
>   "D:\Dev\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe"
>   is configured in the kit. Please update your kit or choose a mkspec
>   for qmake that matches your target environment better.
>
> :-1: avertissement :
>   "D:\Dev\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-g++"
>   is used by qmake, but
>   "D:\Dev\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe"
>   is configured in the kit. Please update your kit or choose a mkspec
>   for qmake that matches your target environment better.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall everything. It seems obvious, but i don't know how to solve this.
[image]

Comment: IIRC I had some funky issues with newer version of the NDK and Qt, which is why I still use the good old r10. If you can't fix the problem manually you may want to try an older version.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the same warning messages with ndk10.
qmake uses arm-linux-androideabi-gcc but the kit is configured to use arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe. How can i modify that?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct Qt installed? Post screenshots of the `Compilers`, `Qt Versions` and `Kits` pages from Creator's Options->Build and Run.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Please unconsider the first kit. It remained after i deleted the ndk r10.

Comment: So you thought that showing the kit settings for the kit that I should "unconsider" is a good idea? Select the kit that matters and then make the screenshot, so I can see its settings.

Comment: My mistake, i modified the screenshot.

Comment: Well, everything looks alright, so maybe try deleting the profiles.xml file, start creator again and see if that helps.

Comment: Still have this warning.